# TrackPopupMenu while mouse is already down

Tags: winapi

Photoshop has a toolbar in which when you press a button and you keep the mouse down, a popup menu is presented after a second.

Trying to do the same, on left down I start a thread that waits for a second, then checks if the button is still down (by a global flag that is released on WM_LBUTTONUP) and then calls TrackPopupMenu():

```
        auto hPr = CreatePopupMenu();
        AppendMenu(hPr, MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR)1, L"Option 1");
        AppendMenu(hPr, MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR)2, L"Option 2");
        int tcmd = TrackPopupMenu(hPr, TPM_CENTERALIGN | TPM_RETURNCMD, po.x, po.y, 0, trg, 0);
        DestroyMenu(hPr);
        if (tcmd == 1) { ...}
```

The problem is that TrackPopupMenu never displays the menu. It returns 0.  This could happen because the left mouse button is already down.
Is there any solution to this? How Photoshop could do it?

Comment: *"I start a thread that waits for a second"* - Why not start a timer on the calling thread instead?

Comment: @IInspectable, yes, silly of me. Post an answer please.

Comment: Agreed. Start a timer on button down, stop the timer on button up. If the timer elapses, stop the timer and show the pop-up menu.